# launch instance using "beginCreatingDeployment" method from Azure Java sdk

Tags: java, azure

I've been browsing the whole web searching for any sample for launching a virtual machine azure java sdk but I found no thing. I read the sdk documentation but I discusses what the method does and what parameters to send but no info with any use case of it. Any quick example for how to create instance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On Azure, there are two kind of Azure Management APIs contain Azure Resource Management & Azure Service Management. For virtual machines, you can refer to these documents of `Virtual Machines REST` & `Virtual Machines (classic) REST` to know them, please see below.

1. Virtual Machines REST for Resource Management: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163647.aspx
2. Virtual Machines (classic) REST for Service Management: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157206.aspx

According to your needs for creating and starting an Azure VM, you can use the Azure Resource Management APIs to do these, please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163630.aspx to know these APIs usage, because of the Java SDK wrapped these REST APIs.

For Azure Java SDK, you can force on the package `com.microsoft.azure.management.compute`, please refer to the Javadoc http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/.

And there is an example called `CreateVMExample.java` using Java SDK from Azure GitHub site, please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/azure-mgmt-samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/samples/compute/CreateVMExample.java.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.